# OnItemCommand of asp:Repeater not working with validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

the function in `OnItemCommand` of the `asp:Repeater` is not working randomly. It's a normal one coded like this.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="control01" OnItemCommand="control01_OnItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_button" CommandArgument='1'>Click</asp:LinkButton></li>        
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

After some time spent on debug I found it's related a input text box on page.

`<asp:TextBox ID="txt_input" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

Only if it's correct value (validated) the function works well.

If I remove `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` and `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` on the text box here

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rvDecimal" ControlToValidate="txt_input" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid value" ValidationExpression="^(-)?\d+(\.\d\d)?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfd_input" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_input" Text="Please enter a valid value"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

`OnItemCommand` got fired and the function works well.

The question is, how can I keep the validation and make the function in `OnItemCommand` working?

Comment: What's `ValidatorEnable($get(CONTROL_ID), true);` supposed to be? Can you at least post the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: @Leo edtied the question with code and more details added.

Comment: I was actually hoping to get the `ValidatorEnable($get(CONTROL_ID), true);` part clarified which looks like js code. have you checked for JS errors? If there are js errors the page might not postback...

Comment: @Leo I've checked that the `ValidatorEnable` in jQuery is irrelevant so I just removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved the problem by adding `CausesValidation="false"` in the control.

`<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_button" CausesValidation="false">`

This would skip the validation the trigger the function in `OnItemCommand`

Comment: Cheers, very handy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the postback to occur even when a validation fails, you can disable the client validation:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rvDecimal" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false" ... />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfd_input" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false" ... />
```

If you want to see an indicator besides each field, showing that its data is not valid, then the validators should have a `Text` property.

On the other hand, if you want a list of failed validations, you can add a ValidationSummary to the page and an `ErrorMessage` to each validator.

Comment: thanks that sounds like a solution. However for my case, I would like to keep the validation for other controls in my page, while skipping this only in the particular control `LinkButton`.